# A way to upgrade

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, connection, 13.10, software-updater

5 along side win 7. I have really bad internet, connected to a router and the connection dose not stay on for a decent 2 hours without resetting. Is their a way to upgrade without having the updater re-update itself after every connection reset? It would be cool if like torrent, it pause and resume on connection!

Answer (score 2):

If you do it from the terminal, `apt` remembers what it has already downloaded, and it should just reasume where it left off. It is the same with `yum` on Fedora.

To update with apt in the terminal, do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to do a dist upgarde (ie. ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10) then do:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

for more info see https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt-get.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: will it automatically resume after the connections get back on?

Comment: And its not letting me to a distro upgrade! I guess its the connection.

Comment: no, but it may hang on for longer (ie. keep on trying the connection until it gets back on). I don't have ubuntu install right now, but if you type `man apt-get` you will maybe get the info you are looking for.